# Measuring performance for controls

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to analyze my own controls in my wpf app.

What the correct way to do that? I want to measuring from the control created level till rendering on the screen, which events can I use for start the stopwatch and stop?

Answer (score 1):

The [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class can be of help in very specific cases, but I recommend using a profiler of some sort, which is much more reliable and easier to use.

You could use a regular .NET profiler, which does a pretty good job analyzing your entire application. One I have used and liked is [Redgate's ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/).

For WPF you have a [Performance Suite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from Microsoft taylored to analyze WPF applications. That might be of good help too.

Comment: The problem is that i need to measure in my code, without 3rd app, because of it i ask when to start the stopwatch and when to stop, how wpf performance suit is works? i cannot to do same thing in my code

Comment: That is virtually impossible since you can't change the code from Microsoft to put in your own. A profiler is what you need. Either build your own, or use existing ones.